How do I use Firebase Sign-in providers (Google OAuth and Apple OAuth) inside my Telegram Mini App?
Question:
How do I use Firebase Sign-in providers (Google OAuth and Apple OAuth) inside my Telegram Mini App?
Explanation:
In my web application (Single-page web application) I use user authentication via Firebase Sign-in providers (Google OAuth and Apple OAuth).
If I open my web application in a standard browser on a mobile device, I can easily authorize the user through Firebase Sign-in providers (Google OAuth and Apple OAuth).
There are 2 problems:
If my web application is opened inside a Telegram bot as a Telegram Mini App, user authentication via Firebase Sign-in providers (Google OAuth and Apple OAuth) does not work:
1) When trying to authorize a Google OAuth user on Android, my Telegram Mini App does not open the standard Google account selection page for user verification – endless waiting for a response from Google.
2) When trying to authorize an Apple OAuth user on iOS, my Telegram Mini App opens the standard authentication page in the Safari browser, not in the Telegram Mini App!
How do I authenticate a user inside my Telegram Mini App?
Help me solve this problem!
I understand that this behavior of my Single-page web application is related to the specifics of the internal WebView browser from Telegram. But perhaps the operation of this WebView from Telegram can be controlled?
